# Apache Camel MultiCasting - InvalidPayloadException

Tags: java, apache-camel

I am trying to use the Multi-Casting enterprise integration pattern (EIP) with Apache Camel but running into lots of Runtime Exceptions. I think the main error is below. If someone could please help me figure this out I think I could probably get this little program to run. Please see the error and program below.

Error: `Caused by: org.apache.camel.InvalidPayloadException: No body available of type: java.io.InputStream but has value: 100 of type: java.lang.Integer on: Message: 100. Caused by: No type converter available to convert from type: java.lang.Integer to the required type: java.io.InputStream with value 100. Exchange[Message: 100]. Caused by: [org.apache.camel.NoTypeConversionAvailableException - No type converter available to convert from type: java.lang.Integer to the required type: java.io.InputStream with value 100]`

Program:

The Java class with the main method to initiate the program:

```
import org.apache.camel.CamelContext;
import org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext;
import org.apache.camel.ProducerTemplate;

public class MainMulti {

    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        CamelContext c = new DefaultCamelContext();

        try { 
        c.addRoutes(new MultiRoute());
        c.start();
        ProducerTemplate pro = c.createProducerTemplate();

        pro.sendBody("direct:start", 100);
        pro.sendBody("direct:start", 500);

        Thread.sleep(5000);

        c.stop();

        } catch(Exception ex) { 
            System.out.println(ex);
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }


    }

}
```

The Java DSL route:

```
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;

public class MultiRoute extends RouteBuilder {

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {

        from("direct:start")
                .multicast(new HighestAggregator())
                    .parallelProcessing()
                    .to("file:target/a", "file:target/b", "file:target/c")
                .end()
                .to("file:target/result");
    }

}
```

The aggregation Java bean:

```
import org.apache.camel.Exchange;
import org.apache.camel.processor.aggregate.AggregationStrategy;

public class HighestAggregator implements AggregationStrategy {


    public Exchange aggregate(Exchange oldExchange, Exchange newExchange) {
        if (oldExchange == null) {
            return newExchange;
        }

        Integer currentQuote = oldExchange.getIn().getBody(Integer.class);
        Integer newQuote = newExchange.getIn().getBody(Integer.class);
        return currentQuote.compareTo(newQuote) > 0 ? oldExchange : newExchange;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are writing to files in the multicast, and the incoming message body is not in a supported type. You send the input as an integer. And writing a single integer to a file is not supported out of the box.

So change the sample code to send in the data as a String instead, eg

```
pro.sendBody("direct:start", "100");
pro.sendBody("direct:start", "500");
```

Comment: Hello Claus, thank-you for accepting the challenge and answering this question. Changing the Integers to Strings does allow the program to run. I thought it would do something else but it does run. I also changed the algorithm in the `aggregate` method of the Java bean to create Integers from the Strings by passing the Strings to the Integer constructor. Also of course, first of all, I had to change the `aggregate` algorithm  to accept the `String.class` from the body of the exchange instead of `Integer.class`. Now if only the program did what I wanted it to... :D :)